# Form validation doesn't work

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

I'm using Angular with Material, and when I try to use Material's form validation and passing the form's values in the (ngSubmit), the value is empty. If I remove [formControl] from the inputs, the values will appear in the Login function's console.log message.

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Login(loginForm.value)">

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Username" ngModel name="username" [formControl]="UNFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="UNMatcher" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="PCFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Username is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" value="" ngModel name="password" [formControl]="PwdFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="passwordMatcher" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="PwdFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Password is <strong>required</strong>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="button-container">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="UNFormControl.hasError('required') || PwdFormControl.hasError('required')">Log In</button>
</div>

<a class="inline-link margin-top-25">Forgot your Password?</a></form>
```

Any thoughs what's going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: If you use Angular with Material, you are using a Template driven forms (so, you can not use [formName], these is for Reactive Form)